# How to install RStoolbox package in R (4.3.2)?

Tags: r

I would like to install RStoolbox package using "install.packages("RStoolbox")", however it shows "Warning in

```
install.packages :
  package ‘RStoolbox’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages"
```

And I choose

```
library(devtools)
install_github("bleutner/RStoolbox")
```

It notice that

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [RStoolbox.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RStoolbox’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/library/RStoolbox’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/dz/hfv4f1hd73j_0hnn3551kc5h0000gn/T//RtmpxVCBIG/file23d12d40b3cd/RStoolbox_0.3.1.9999.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Install gfortran, see canonical.

Comment: 'library not found for -lgfortran':  you are missing a Fortran compiler for R, and hence fail to build from source.  There are other answers here showing where to get one from for macOS, if I recall the recommended route is https://mac.r-project.org/tools/